# ASP.NET Route Not Hitting Default with T4MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, t4mvc

This wasnt happening before but all of a sudden I am not hitting my default route anymore.  My homepage goes to `http://localhost:2222/assets/images/30?Controller=home&Action=index`.  Why would this be happening?

I noticed when I am in a action on the home controller it works fine, but if I go to another controller this problem occurs.

```
@foreach(var t in MVC.Home.Index().GetRouteValueDictionary())
    {
        <span>@t.Key - @t.Value</span>
    }

Area - Controller - home Action - index
```

Link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", MVC.Home.Index())
```

Global.asax

```
 routes.Add(
                "Images",
                new Route(
                    "assets/images/{Id}",
                        new RouteValueDictionary(),
                        new RouteValueDictionary { { "Id", "\\d+" } },
                        new ImageRouteHandler(new ImageHandler())
                    )
                );


            routes.MapRouteLowercase(
               "Default",


                  "{controller}/{action}",


                   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area="" }
                   );
```

HomeController.cs

```
public partial class HomeController : SiteController


     {
          public virtual ActionResult Index()
                {
                    var model = new HomeViewModel();


                    return View(model);
                }
```

T4MVC.cs

```
   public class ActionNamesClass {
            public readonly string Index = ("Index").ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

Comment: How is that link generated.  It looks like you are supplying a route value Id=30 which would match the first route in preference, regardless of the controller and/or action name.  You might want to consider adding a controller constraint as well

Comment: Good point I added that its generated using t4mvc.

Comment: Just out of interest, look at the Glimpse NuGet package, it has a route debugger tab

Comment: What is the route dictionary generated by the MVC.Home.Index() call, and what is the signature of the Index method on the Home controller

Comment: What generated code from the Index METHOD from the T4MVC.cs file

Comment: Can you post the result of MVC.Home.Index().GetRouteValueDictionary()

Comment: Also, did you make sure you transformed all templates, to regenerate the T4MVC code?

Comment: I did regenerate the code, and I added the route value above.

Comment: I noticed when I am in a action on a home controller it works fine, but if I go to another controller this problem occurs.

Comment: try take out the Images route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and reversed the default route, and assets route and everything is working, weird.